# Merge lines without period at the end in notepad++

Tags: merge, notepad++

I have a text from a PDF that breaks lines :S

I want to join the lines that do not end in a period (or point).

EG:

```
STAN LEE: There are over
six billion people on Earth.
Genetically, most of us are
almost the same.
But every now and then,
a mutation occurs.
```

in

```
STAN LEE: There are over six billion people on Earth.
Genetically, most of us are almost the same.
But every now and then, a mutation occurs.
```

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the find and replace. Set the `regular expressions` option at the bottom. The search for

```
([^.])\r\n
```

and replace with

```
\1_
```

`_` is a space here.

Comment: that expression finds nothing

Comment: @JesicaArroyoSalvador you have to select `regular expressions` at the bottom of the find dialog.